# compare (aliased) template templates

Tags: templates, c++17

I'm wondering if it is possible to compare / simplify / canonicalize template template parameters.

I.e. I have a

```
template <template <typename...> class CONTAINER>
struct spam;
```

and would like to check if two spam types are the same

```
template <typename T>
using vectoralias = std::vector<T>;

std::is_same_v<spam<std::vector>,spam<vectoralias>>; // is false, where I (too) naively would've expected true.
```

[compiler-explorer link](https://godbolt.org/z/LILswM).

I assume comparing equality of two templated types without spelling out the template parameter is hard as the two templated types I'm comparing may contain complicated `enable_if` or `conditional`, but in the simple case of an alias like here, I'm wondering if there might be a way.