# "decay" a templated alias

Tags: c++, c++17, template-argument-deduction, template-templates

This is a followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56009136/4588453).

I'm having a templated type with a template template argument

```cpp
template <template <typename...> class CONTAINER, typename NUMBERTYPE>
struct spam {
    template <class T>
    using Temp = CONTAINER<T>;
};
```

I want to write a (templated) function that takes a `spam` instance and returns a `spam` instance of a *slightly* different type. I want to maintain the `CONTAINER` template parameter from the input and only specify the `NUMBERTYPE`. ([godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/xUbw14))

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template <template <typename...> class CONTAINER, typename NUMBERTYPE>
struct spam {
    template <class T>
    using Temp = CONTAINER<T>;
};

template <typename T>
auto function(T in) {
    spam<T::template Temp, double> retval;
    return retval;
}

int main() {
    spam<std::vector, float> one;
    // spam<std::vector, double> two = function(one);
    auto two = function(one);
    return 0;
}
```

This mostly works, but I wanted to check if `function()` returns the type I expected by receiving the expected `spam<std::vector, double>` rather than accepting an `auto` return. The non-auto version does not compile because

```
<source>:18:45: error: conversion from 'spam<spam<std::vector, float>::Temp,[...]>' to non-scalar type 'spam<std::vector,[...]>' requested

     spam<std::vector, double> two = function(one);

                                     ~~~~~~~~^~~~~
```

i.e. I have a mismatch between `spam<std::vector, double>` and `spam<spam<std::vector, float>::template Temp, doulbe>`, although I expect that `spam<std::vector, float>::template Temp` is the same as `std::vector`. (In fact I can check that `std::is_same_v<spam<std::vector, float>::template Temp<int>, std::vector<int>>` is indeed true - i.e. after providing the template arguments to `Temp` I have expected/desired behaviour, just that the code I'm contributing to works mostly with the unresolved `CONTAINER`).

QUESTION: is there a way to normalize `T::template Temp` to whatever it is and remove the `spam<...>::Temp` from the type?

Comment: Not that this nitpick helps you, but `T::template Temp` is _not_ a type, contrary to what your last sentence says.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> QUESTION: is there a way to normalize T::template Temp to whatever it is and remove the spam<...>::Temp from the type?

No, as far I know.

But isn't necessary, in this case, because you can rewrite `function()` to intercept the template-template parameter `CONTAINER`.

I mean: you can rewrite `function()` as follows

```
template <template <typename...> class C, typename N>
spam<C, double> function (spam<C, N> const &)
 { return {}; }
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template <template <typename...> class CONTAINER, typename NUMBERTYPE>
struct spam
 {
   template <typename T>
   using Temp = CONTAINER<T>;
 };

template <template <typename...> class C, typename N>
spam<C, double> function (spam<C, N> const &)
 { return {}; }

int main() {
    spam<std::vector, float> one;
    spam<std::vector, double> two = function(one);
    auto three = function(one);
}
```